# Styling modals within React

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, bootstrap-modal

I am making a few separate pages which each containing a modal (or two). I have made a css styling sheet to make JUST ONE of these full screen I would like the rest to stay the same size.

However this has affected all of my modals not just one.

My first course of action was to remove this modal (and the css sheet)from the folder it was contained within in a hope that the css style sheet would no longer affect the other modals now it is outside of the folder. This did not work.

So essentially I feel as if inline styling in this instance is the best course of action.However I am not sure how to do the styling for this specific modal.

I am here asking for any advice on how to either tackle the styling sheet issue or how to make this work through inline styling.

Here is my folder structure as you can see adminviewWorkstatioModal is in a separate folder along with viewWorkstationModal.css however the style of this still affects the rest of the files in the picture.

[image]

Example of one of the modals(template only)

```
class DisplayAddQuestion extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.handleClose = this.handleClose.bind(this);
    this.handleShow = this.handleShow.bind(this);

    this.handleRefresh = this.handleRefresh.bind(this);

    this.state = {
      show: false,
      show1: false
    };
  }

  handleClose() {
    this.setState({
      show: false,
      show1: false
    });
  }

  handleShow() {
    this.setState({
      show: true
    });
  }

  handleRefresh() {
    window.location.reload();
  }

  render() {
    // console.log(this.state);

    return (
      <div className="header-container">
        <button
          className="btn btn-primary"
          style={{ float: "right" }}
          onClick={this.handleShow}
        >
          +
        </button>

        <Modal
          className="modal-container custom-map-modal"
          show={this.state.show}
          onHide={this.handleClose}
          animation={true}
        >
           <Modal.Header closeButton></Modal.Header>
          <Modal.Body></Modal.Body> 
        </Modal>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

And finally the css sheet

```
.modal-dialog {
  width: 100% !important;
  height: 100% !important;
  margin: 0 !important;
  padding: 0 !important;
  max-width: none !important;
}

.modal-content {
  height: auto !important;
  min-height: 100% !important;
  border-radius: 0 !important;
  background-color: #ececec !important;
}

.modal-header {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #9ea2a2 !important;
}

.modal-footer {
  border-top: 1px solid #9ea2a2 !important;
}
```

Thanks in advance !!

Comment: Is there any reason you can't put a style class on the one modal? That would be par for the course in any web page.

Comment: HI I did what you suggested and it worked. If you would like to write this as a answer I can mark it as the answer.

Comment: I don't have a specific solution in mind--just the general idea. Go ahead and write one up with your solution and accept it.